# Pandas Index Excess Precision Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I want my index to have a decimal precision of 3, but Pandas is forcing the index to a much higher level of precision.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
temprange = [j*.001 for j in range(1,int(10/.001)+1)]
print temprange[:5]
>> [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005]
print pd.DataFrame(index=temprange).index.tolist()[:5]
>> [0.001, 0.002, 0.0030000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001]
```

How do I keep the index in original form?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html and any specific reasons for precision?